# Octopress build fails when trying to install Code Ray Syntax Highlighter Plugin for Octopress

Tags: rubygems, liquid, octopress

I am using the kramdown version of markdown.
I haven't deployed yet which means I only have 
a source but no Masters folder.

The build fails with following liquid exception: Unknown tag coderay.

The coderay plugin is registered in a file called code_ray_block.rb
which i simply copied and pasted under the plugin folder.
In addition I copied two files and placed them under Sass folder.
_coderay-github.scss and _styles.scss
I havent installed a plugin before but i am guessing that there's not much more to it.

I am trying to follow the instructions given here:
https://github.com/JanStevens/Octopress-CodeRay-Syntax-Highlighter

Also I am not sure what is being referred to as main scss file..is that the one under custom folder?
"For the stylesheets in the sass folder you need to copy them somewhere and then only include _styles.scss in your main scss file."

Bundle show displays both kramdown and coderay as included in the gemfile.
I use rake generate or rake preview commands only. Preview was not displaying
any syntax highlightening even with the default install and then i tried with this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I've also followed Jan Stevens' Octopress CodeRay Syntax Highlighter tutorial and hit the same problem. I've provided a fix [here](http://cristianadam.eu/20150510/from-blogger-to-octopress/).

The diff to code_ray_block.rb is below:

```
diff -ur old/code_ray_block.rb new/code_ray_block.rb
--- old/code_ray_block.rb    Sun May 10 16:57:33 2015
+++ new/code_ray_block.rb    Sun Mar 15 11:11:13 2015 @@ -48,12 +48,11 @@    require './plugins/pygments_code'  require './plugins/raw'
+require 'coderay'    module Jekyll
     class CodeRayBlock < Liquid::Block
-    include HighlightCode
-    include TemplateWrapper
     CaptionUrlTitle = /(\S[\S\s]*)\s+(https?:\/\/\S+|\/\S+)\s*(.+)?/i
     Caption = /(\S[\S\s]*)/   @@ -96,7 +95,7 @@
       else
         source += " #{CodeRay.scan(code, :text).div(:css => coderay_css, :line_numbers => line_numbers)} </figure>"
       end
-      source = safe_wrap(source)
+      source = TemplateWrapper::safe_wrap(source)
       source = context['pygments_prefix'] + source if context['pygments_prefix']
       source = source + context['pygments_suffix'] if context['pygments_suffix']
       source
```